# Download HTML table colspan and rowspan no picked up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML table:

```
<a href="#" id ="download" role='button' class="button">Download</a>
<div id="dvData" class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Example</th>
            <th colspan="7">Larger Header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_headers">
            <th colspan="3">Sub Header 1</th>
            <th colspan="3">Sub Header 2</th>
            <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle">Sub Header 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_headers">
            <th>Sub sub header</th>
            <th>Sub sub header</th>
            <th>Sub sub header</th>
            <th>Sub sub header</th>
            <th>Sub sub header</th>
            <th>Sub sub header</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
            <td> Info</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I have the following JavaScript to download the table:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {//used to export tables
        var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)')
            ,$rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)')
            ,tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11) // vertical tab character
            ,tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0) // null character
            ,colDelim = '","'
            ,rowDelim = '"\r\n"';

            var csv = '"';
            csv += formatRows($headers.map(grabRow));
            csv += rowDelim;
            csv += formatRows($rows.map(grabRow)) + '"';

            var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(encodeURI(csv))], {
                type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
            });
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            $(this)
                .attr({
                    'download': filename
                    ,'href': csvData
            });
        }
        function formatRows(rows){
            return rows.get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim);
        }
        function grabRow(i,row){

            var $row = $(row);
            var $cols = $row.find('td'); 
            if(!$cols.length) $cols = $row.find('th');  

            return $cols.map(grabCol)
                        .get().join(tmpColDelim);
        }
        function grabCol(j,col){
            var $col = $(col),
                $text = $col.text();

            return $text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

        }
    }
$("#download").click(function (event) {
        outputFile = "example.csv"
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData > table'), outputFile]);
    });
```

When I download the file the headers get messed up. The colspan and rowspan properties are not kept. How do I fix that?

EDIT: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ALUW/2s1z9pa9/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ALUW/2s1z9pa9/

Comment: CSV doesn't have a notion of row span or column span.

Comment: So how do I go about getting the headers to be placed where I need them?

Comment: You... get creative? Each column is comma separated, right? So put in enough commas to get the column header roughly aligned to where you want them.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's not exactly what you want, but can export it to Excel, retaining the headers exactly as you want:

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/f2qh0t2b/1/

```
function generateExcel(el) {
    var clon = el.clone();
    var html = clon.wrap('<div>').parent().html();

    //add more symbols if needed...
    while (html.indexOf('á') != -1) html = html.replace(/á/g, '&aacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('é') != -1) html = html.replace(/é/g, '&eacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('í') != -1) html = html.replace(/í/g, '&iacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('ó') != -1) html = html.replace(/ó/g, '&oacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('ú') != -1) html = html.replace(/ú/g, '&uacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('º') != -1) html = html.replace(/º/g, '&ordm;');
    html = html.replace(/<td>/g, "<td>&nbsp;");

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
$("#download").click(function (event) {
    generateExcel($("#example"));
});
```

Comment: There is a little pop up before the excel opens. I really appreciate the solution but I'm trying to make it as clean as possible.

Comment: Yes, the popup it's a bummer, but I'm using this function and all the users like it.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the pop up? The method I'm using right now doesn't have one.

Comment: I couldn't find any, and I tried several ways. I think the only way it's to generate a native xlsx, but it's too complex to do it in Javascript

Comment: And what about csv?

Comment: It's a PITA, you depend on the excel configuration for the separator (comma or semicolon), and other several format problem that can render the csv unusable

Comment: I usually use server side generated native excel, but have this option in all the tables in my app, just in case the user need it